# I have to check string validator with my code but upper case is showing wrong result

Tags: python-3.x

```
for i in s:
            if i.isupper() == True:
                print('True')
                break
            else:
                if i == s[l-1:]:
                    if i.isupper() == False:
                        print('False')
                        break
                    else:
                        continue
                elif i.islower() == False:
                    continue
```

Input:- #$%@^&*kjnk svskjnbui h 4oi3hheuh /dfh uidshvhdsuihv suihc 0hrem89m4c02mw4xo;,wh fwhncoishmxlxfkjsahnxu83v 08 n8OHOIHIOMOICWHOFCMHEOFMCOEJMC0J09C 03J J3L;JMFC3JM3JC3'JIOO9MMJ099U N090N9 OOHOLNHNLLKNLKNKNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK3333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Output:- True

I have to check that this input contains any uppercase value or not, my code run well for all other inputs but for this input it is showing "False" but the correct answer is "True".

Comment: i checked your code. it works. Not sure why it is not working for you. Can you tell me how you are storing the input into `s` ?  I just had the following code `for i in s:` tab `if i.isupper():` tab `print('True')` next line and below print `break` And it breaks at O and prints True

Comment: When i'm running my code is giving False as a output but the correct answer is true.

Comment: I'm storing input into s as a string, i have simply applied s = input().

Answer (score 1):

Probably because your string has a single quote in it, pass `'` as `\'` instead.

Also Try this one liner:

```
if any(x.upper for x in string):
    print('True')
else:
    print('False')
```

Comment: No, it's not working. It shows True for this input but shows wrong output for other inputs.

Comment: Are you sure, everytime you pass a  '  or  "  should be passed as  \'  or  \"

Answer (score 0):

if **name** == '**main**':

```
s = input()
import re
k = re.search('[a-zA-Z0-9]',s)
if(k is None):
    print('False')
else:
    print('True') 
k = re.search('[a-zA-Z]',s)
if(k is None):
    print('False')
else:
    print('True') 
k = re.search('[0-9]',s)
if(k is None):
    print('False')
else:
    print('True') 

k = re.search('[a-z]',s)
if(k is None):
    print('False')
else:
    print('True')    
    
k = re.search('[A-Z]',s)
if(k is None):
    print('False')
else:
    print('True')
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).